# Is it possible to use lodash in PouchDB map function?

Tags: mapreduce, lodash, pouchdb

I would like to create a design document in PouchDB and in the map function to make use of `lodash` and `moment`. Ideally I'd like to achieve a similar result with following hypothetical example;

```
import {get} from 'lodash';
import moment from 'moment';

const mapFn = (doc, emit) => {
  emit([
     get(doc, 'context.location'),
     moment(get(doc, 'context.start')).format('DD-MMM-YYYY')
  ], get(doc, 'payments.total'));

};

db.put({
  _id: `_design/myIndex`,
    views: {
      myIndex: {
        map: mapFn.toString()
    }
  }
})
```

Due to `toString()` the scope is voided. Is there any way to inject these libraries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proposed solution might work, but isn't the cleanest solution (it relies on globals and works only when your app is present, but it would break if you try to replicate your data and use the view somewhere else).

There is a better solution that would also work with replication, e.g. with CouchDB: Use CommonJS `require()` in your view. [See the CouchDB docs for more info](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/couchapp/ddocs.html?highlight=commonjs#map-functions). There is also an [example for using CommonJS](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/query-server/javascript.html#commonjs) in the docs.

Just use `views.lib.lodash = lodash.toString();` to stringify it, then you can use it as a require from within the view function:

```
mapFn = (doc, emit) => {
  var _ = require('views/lib/lodash');
  var moment = require('views/lib/moment');

  emit([
     _.get(doc, 'context.location'),
     moment(_.get(doc, 'context.start')).format('DD-MMM-YYYY')
  ], _.get(doc, 'payments.total'));
};
```

Take into account that whenever you update lodash, your views will be invalidated (in theory, a new lodash version could produce different view results). You also cannot just stringify `get` from lodash, because you will lose context. You can `npm install lodash.get` and use it, this should be self-contained. And always use the self-contained versions for the browser, because `require()s` within the library won't work because of the different paths.

But in your case, I'd rather use a simple helper function instead of requiring a bigger library, this is too much of a trade-off.

Comment: Ah this is amazing! Thanks a lot. I'll accept your answer as soon as I try it out.

Comment: Evan when answering another user's question I found out that the info from the legacy wiki is already in the new CouchDB docs. I changed the link to reflect the more current information. Just use `views.lib.lodash =  lodash.toString();` to stringify it, then you can use it as a require from within the view function: `var lodash = require('views/lib/lodash');`.

Take into account that whenever you update lodash, your views will be invalidated (in theory, a new lodash version could produce different view results).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the answer is straightforward, to expose `lodash` and `moment` to `window` or `self` when you use web workers. Then when pouchDB `eval`s the function, the references are resolved.